# Websphere. Get thread pool ID

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-7

I need to build string with the following pattern:

```
<Server>;<Node>;<Cell>;<Version>;<MessageListenerThreadPool-ID>;<ORBThreadPool-
ID>;<WebcontainerThreadPool-ID>;<TCPChannelsThreadPool-ID>
```

So I need to write the ID's of several standard thread pools, but I can't find any information about thread-pools Id's. I found only thread-pool names. May be somebody knows where I can find information about thread-pool Id's?

Thanks!

P.S. I'm using Websphere 7.x

Comment: What is a "thread pool ID"?  What do you intend to do with the ID?

Comment: @bkail I don't know what is thread pool ID. But I need to get it from WAS. This string (mentioned in question) is used in one of the IBM products.

Comment: A Google search turns up "IBM FileNet System Monitor"; is that the product?  If yes, it appears to need the configuration ID, which appears to be available from JMX.

Comment: @bkail hm, yes, is FSM. Can you explain little more deeper about retrieving this thread-pool ID?  Thanks.

Comment: The FSM monitoring guide suggests it can be obtained from JMX.  I have no experience with FSM, sorry.

Comment: Do you need to get that information once (manually) or do you need to get that information dynamically at runtime (in an application that is deployed on WebSphere)?

Comment: @AndreasVeithen yes, only once. I found answer to my question, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to my question.

Thread-pool ID can be obtained from **JConsole**, under *Threadpool* node. There many thread-pools, and thread-pools Mbeans listed in question have an **objectName** attribute, like this:

> WebSphere:name=ORB.thread.pool,process=server1,platform=dynamicproxy,.......server.xml#ThreadPool_1183122130078,cell=someCell,spec=1.0

In this case Thread-pool ID is **1183122130078**.

Thanks all.

Comment: @ArtemOboturov yes, I know that I need to use JMX (it was written in gude:) ), but I needed a more accurate answer (i.e. I don't understand how to use JMX to obtain ID's, but I know that main way to solve problem - is using JMX).

Comment: Look at code of JConsole (it's open source) at [http://openjdk.java.net/tools/svc/jconsole/](http://openjdk.java.net/tools/svc/jconsole/).

Answer (score 2):

Use JMX to obtain management objects (JSR-77: J2EETM Management). Example of obtaining them from Websphere is given at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0402_qiao/0402_qiao.html.

[This API](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v7r0mx/topic/com.ibm.websphere.wbpmcore.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/management/package-summary.html) will help you to access JXM.

First find if object are accessible via [Administrative console](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rcon_command_assist.html). Then look at list of objects that you'll receive from server via JMX API call.

Answer (score 2):

There does't appear to be a threadpool ID associated with the JMX object; just a threadpool name.  You can write a script similar to the one below to list threadpools and their attributes.

```
wsadmin>pools = AdminConfig.list('ThreadPool').split()
wsadmin>for pool in pools:
wsadmin>        print pool
wsadmin>        print
wsadmin>
Default(cells/cluentiusNode12Cell/nodes/node2/server/provider1|server.xml#ThreadPool_1183121908658)


HAManagerService.Pool(cells/cluentiusNode12Cell/nodes/node2/servers/provider1|hamanagerservice.xml#ThreadPool_1080665401693)

Message.Listener.Pool(cells/cluentiusNode12Cell/nodes/node2/servers/provider1|server.xml#ThreadPool_1183121908663)

ORB.thread.pool(cells/cluentiusNode12Cell/nodes/node2/servers/provider1|server.xml#ThreadPool_1183121908656)

... snip ...

WMQJCAResourceAdapter(cells/cluentiusNode12Cell/nodes/node2/servers/provider1|server.xml#ThreadPool_1332907301375)

WebContainer(cells/cluentiusNode12Cell/nodes/node2/servers/provider1|server.xml#ThreadPool_1183121908657)

server.startup(cells/cluentiusNode12Cell/nodes/node2/servers/provider1|server.xml#ThreadPool_1183121908662)

wsadmin>print AdminConfig.show(pools[9])
[customProperties []]
[inactivityTimeout 60000]
[isGrowable false]
[maximumSize 10]
[minimumSize 5]
[name WebContainer]
wsadmin>
```

The show() command shows the attributes you do have available to you.